# How to extract only rows matching condition 'WHERE column1 ILIKE column2' (where column1 is integer and column2 is jsonb)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I am using postgresql.

Let's suppose I have this table name `my_table`:

```
  id | idcm |  stores |     du     |     au     |              dtc              | 
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 | 20447 | [2, 5] | 2022-11-02 | 2022-11-15 | 2022-11-03 11:12:19.213799+01 | 
   2 | 20456 | [2, 5] | 2022-11-02 | 2022-11-15 | 2022-11-03 11:12:19.213799+01 | 
   3 | 20478 | [2, 5] | 2022-11-02 | 2022-11-15 | 2022-11-03 11:12:19.213799+01 | 
   4 | 20482 | [2, 5] | 2022-11-02 | 2022-11-15 | 2022-11-03 11:12:19.213799+01 | 
   5 | 20485 | [2, 5] | 2022-11-02 | 2022-11-15 | 2022-10-25 20:25:08.949996+02 | 
   6 | 20497 | [2, 5] | 2022-11-02 | 2022-11-15 | 2022-10-25 20:25:08.949996+02 |
   7 | 20499 | [2, 5] | 2022-11-02 | 2022-11-15 | 2022-10-25 20:25:08.949996+02 |
```

I want to select only the rows having the value of `id` equal to one of the elements of the array in `stores` (of that line).
However, the type of `stores` is not array, it is jsonb.

So I want to get something like this:

```
  id | idcm |  stores |     du     |     au     |              dtc              | 
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2 | 20456 | [2, 5] | 2022-11-02 | 2022-11-15 | 2022-11-03 11:12:19.213799+01 | 
   5 | 20485 | [7, 5] | 2022-11-02 | 2022-11-15 | 2022-10-25 20:25:08.949996+02 | 
   6 | 20497 | [2, 6] | 2022-11-02 | 2022-11-15 | 2022-10-25 20:25:08.949996+02 |
   7 | 20499 | [5, 7] | 2022-11-02 | 2022-11-15 | 2022-10-25 20:25:08.949996+02 |
```

I have tryed with

```
select * from my_table where stores::text ilike id::text;
```

but it returns zero rows because I would need to put wildcard character `%` before and after `id`,

so I have tryed with

```
select * from my_table where stores::text ilike %id%::text;
```

but I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [contains operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) after converting the ID to a single JSON value:

```
select *
from the_table
where stores @> to_jsonb(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
select * from my_table where id = any(stores);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample :

```
create table stores_table (id serial, stores jsonb);
```

Then add samples values :

```
insert into stores_table (stores) values ('[2,5]'), ('[2, 5]'), ('[2,6]'), ('[4,7]');
```

Search stores containing id :

```
select * from stores_table where stores @> to_jsonb(id);
```

You will get :

```
 id | stores
 ---+--------
  2 | [2, 5]
  4 | [4, 7]
 (2 rows)
```

Hope this help.